# MediaStream with RTC working on Firefox but no audio on chromium

Tags: javascript, websocket, webrtc, chromium, mediastream

For a friend I try to get video tracks of his stream with Javascript then use it in HTMLVideoElement.

I use RTCPeerConnection and WebSocket for doing this and all go well with firefox, no error, I can see his stream.
But on every chromium navigator, there is no audio.

I searched during hours seeing many solution but nothing seems to work.

I saw that the video track received when used with MediaStream become two tracks in firefox (video and audio) but only one with chromium (video);

In this example of code, the first console.log (event) show in chromium and firefox only one track of type "video".
But the second console.log (tracks) show on firefox 2 tracks (audio and video) and on chromium, only one track (video)

```js
constructor(video)
{ 
    this.#rtc = new RTCPeerConnection();
    this.#stream = new MediaStream();
    if(!video instanceof HTMLVideoElement) return;
    this.#video = video;
}
/**
 * Set the video when a track is received
 * @param {RTCTrackEvent} e 
*/
#onTrack(e)
{
    console.log("event", e.track);
    this.#stream.addTrack(e.track);
    this.#video.srcObject = this.#stream;
    console.log("tracks", this.#stream.getTracks());
}
```

I sent my code on github for people here can see it :
https://github.com/NolwennWM/streaming

Thank you for your help.

Comment: usually that's happen because `CORS` police, i have done with issue like that by following article in https://dev.to/dengel29/loading-local-files-in-firefox-and-chrome-m9f .
i hope that can help you too.

Comment: Hello Kazei, welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for adding code to your question. It may be helpful if you shared link to example video and those log messages you mention.